# How do I publish a Facebook Collection on the Users Timeline per default?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have made a facebook [collection](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/collections/) which is still approved. Now I want that this collection appears per default at the users timeline. I have seen this working for apps like pinterest or soundcloud. How do they manage that the collection will be set on the users timeline per default?

Answer (score 0):

Straight answer: **you can't** (Sorry for the heart break!).

From facebook collection docs:

`A person using your app can optionally add your custom section to their timeline. Custom sections and collections are not added to the timeline by default. Sections are generally opt-in.`

[More reading](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/collections/#customprompt)

So basically a user has to manually add your section. Although I kind of felt that I never added section for **Goodreads** on my timeline, but it was still visible, so I thought there might be some way, but after researching on it for two days I could not find anything definitive as to why this was happening.

Two theories I could come up with (and these are my private take on the issue, so take them with a pinch of salt):

1. **Maybe** facebook adds sections for some *top apps* (well you could argue what that means, but for arguments sake lets say based on number of users) directly on users timeline.
2. Another and more plausible theory: since these apps were created long time ago, maybe they were already added to timeline, before facebook brought the *sections are not added to timeline by default* feature.

Hope this helps.